# Vue3 $attr binds on parent element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I have an Input component like this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-bind="$attrs"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

I want to bind input attributes(like autofocus, placeholder, and...) just on the input tag but it also binds on the parent div tag. The div tag is important and I can't ignore this tag in the Input component. what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there's a single root element (like the `div` in your case), attributes are automatically applied to that element.

You can disable that behavior with [`inheritAttrs=false`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#inheritattrs):

```html
<script>
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-disable-attr-inheritance?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyInput.vue)